# How to take advantage of WPI to distribute our software?

Tags: installation, feed, web-platform-installer

The **[Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)** has an option to load an external **feed** in order to present the user with more products

[image]

> In what **format** should be that feed, what **elements** does it require?

and

> How can we send and setup the database (like Umbraco does)?

***P.S***. Keep in mind that I do not want to [submit the app to Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/developer.aspx), just use the feed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to create a custom feed/xml and add it through the options dialog.

I wrote a series of blogs on how to create custom Web PI feeds:

- [Web PI Extensibility: Custom Feeds – Installing Custom Products](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-products.aspx)
- [Web PI Extensibility: Custom Feeds – Installing Custom Applications](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/10/24/web-pi-extensibility-custom-feeds-installing-custom-applications.aspx)

Here is an example of a product and app that is distributed through a custom feed:

- [Install SIR Web Application with Web PI](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2010/01/25/install-sir-web-application-with-web-pi.aspx)

And here is how you can test whether your feed doesn't have any errors by plugging into Web PI APIs:

- [Web PI APIs: Install a product from a custom feed](http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2010/02/11/webpi-apis-install-a-product-from-a-custom-feed.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the links, the topics and content are amazing, exactly what I've been looking for.